# MSVC 2013 std::async works asynchronously without wait()

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

Here is my code snippet to test if std::async indeed can be launched asynchronously on MSVC2013. And the result seems to verify that ( no pun intended), however the async() blocks on wait(). Now I am confused that so many queries on the forum discussed on the std::async synchronous (blocking) nature. 
  With auto f = async(launch::async, [] {});  the code works still in async mode, but with f.get() it becomes sync.
   What am I doing wrong here? Does std::async have the creation overhead like the std::thread ? Is thread_pool the only answer to all these?

```
   using namespace std;
   mutex mu;

   void print(string s)
   {
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);
      cout << s << endl;
    }

    void foo1()
    {
      async(launch::async, [] 
      { 
         ostringstream ss;  ss << "foo1 " << this_thread::get_id();
         print(ss.str() ) ;  
         this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
         ostringstream ss1;  ss1 << "foo1 " << this_thread::get_id() << "
         just woke up."; print(ss1.str());
      });

      async(launch::async, []
      {
         ostringstream ss;  ss << "foo1 " << this_thread::get_id(); 
         print(ss.str());

         this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

         ostringstream ss1;  ss1 << "foo1 " << this_thread::get_id() << "    
         just woke up."; print(ss1.str());
         });

      }

     int main() 
     {
         foo1();
         this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
     }

     The result shows:
     foo1 6244
     foo1 6240
     foo1 6244 just woke up.
     foo1 6240 just woke up.
     Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Common issue: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: @chris: Thanks for the link. The link says if the future result is harnessed then it is synchronous; if I don't is it still async?

Comment: The thing blocking is the `future` destructor and you have full control over when that runs.

Comment: @chris: I dont use get() and i dont tap the future result, so does that mean I am in async mode?

Comment: @ark1974 no.  If you do not capture the returned future the destructor will block of the returned future.  That makes the code
 run synchronisly

Comment: Futures are non-blocking except for some operations, but you're using the destructor right away if you don't store the result.

Comment: auto f = async(launch::async, [] {}); still the code works async, but if do f.get() it becomes sync.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thanks, see code I didn't capture the future  result and it didn't even block . However it does if I go for future.get()

Comment: Yes, `get` is blocking. If you're looking for a proper future with continuations, then the standard one sadly isn't the right place to look for a while.